# Получение истории платежей QIWI через urllib2

Tags: python, urllib, qiwi

Можно ли получить историю последних платежей на qiwi через модуль urllib2?
Пробовал делать так:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json

token = 'токен'
login = 'номер'
parameters = {'rows': '1'}
params = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
request = urllib2.Request('https://edge.qiwi.com/payment-history/v1/persons/'+login+'/payments', params)
request.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)

try:
    urllib2.urlopen(request)
except Exception, e:
    print e.code
    print e.read()
```

Но получаю это:

> ```
> {"serviceName":"payment-history","errorCode":"http.method.not.supported","userMessage":"Method is not supported","dateTime":"2018-08-06T18:09:11.665+03:00","traceId":"08fcf12f42774ae9"}
> ```

Comment: Пробовали через библиотеку работать https://github.com/mostm/pyqiwi?

Comment: @gil9red нужно только по стандартным пакетам делать, которые не надо устанавливать

Comment: тогда смотрите как в той либе сделана отправка в qiwi, мб найдете ответ :)

Comment: посмотрите какой необходим http-метод (GET, PUT и пр.) и попробуйте руками в curl или аналогах

Comment: @ANDROSHA, раз вы удалили [свой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868371/Получить-переменную-из-функции), напишу в первом попавшемся. Я не минусовал ваш вопрос. По поводу "это я для вопроса написал" - код в вопросе должен демонстрировать проблему. Ваш код в том вопросе показывает, что вы ни разу не запустили функцию, но ждете, что глобальная переменная каким-то магическим образом заполнится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json

token = 'токен'
login = 'номер'
parameters = {'rows': '1'}
params = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
request = urllib2.Request('https://edge.qiwi.com/payment-history/v1/persons/{}/payments?{}'.format(login, params))
request.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer {}'.format(token))

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    #далее действия с полученным ответом
except Exception, e:
    print e.code
    print e.read()
```

Попробуйте такой код, должен работать. Проблема была в том, что вы в запросе передавали строку(*params*) в виде словаря для POST.